# How to pass empty variable from perl cgi to template?

Tags: perl, cgi

I am trying to load entries from the DB and pass them to a template.
If there are no entries in the DB I get a software error.
If I try adding an if condition and define the values I get the error again.
It seems that there is an issue in the loop or the if condition.

Software error:

> HTML::Template::param() : attempt to set parameter 'row' with a scalar
>   - parameter is not a TMPL_VAR! at /path line 133.

Could anybody help either avoiding the error (1st case) for 0 entries or with a different approach?

This code works for >=1 entries:

```
my $sql2="select column1, column2, column3, column4, column 5 FROM TABLE;";
my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn,$username, $password);
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql2);
$sth->execute() or die $DBI::errstr;
my $row;
push @{$row}, $_ while $_ = $sth->fetchrow_hashref();

my $template = HTML::Template->new(filename => 'entries.tmpl');
$template->param(ROW => $row);
```

This code does not work:

```
my $count;
my $sql1="SELECT count(*) FROM TABLE;";
my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn,$username, $password);
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql1);
$sth->execute() or die $DBI::errstr;
$count = $sth->fetchrow_array();

if ($count == 0)
{
my $row;
@row=("There are no entries",0,0,0,0);
}
else {
my $sql2="select column1, column2, column3, column4, column 5 FROM TABLE;";
my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn,$username, $password);
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql2);
$sth->execute() or die $DBI::errstr;
my $row;
push @{$row}, $_ while $_ = $sth->fetchrow_hashref();
}

my $template = HTML::Template->new(filename => 'entries.tmpl');
$template->param(ROW => $row);
```

Comment: If you get an error, share the message.Also share the template

Comment: In the provided code you use `fetchrow_hashref` which returns **hashref**. In second piece of the code you use `@row=("There are no entries",0,0,0,0);` which is an **array** but not **hashref**. My guess that `$template->param(ROW => $row)` gets confused when it gets data in unexpected form.

Comment: Both of your variables `$row`are declared lexically inside the `if` and `else`blocks. They will be out of scope when you try to pass `$row`(a third $row variable) to the template. Always start your code with `use strict; use warnings;`